# Dynamically load a Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nuget, add-in

I am currently writing a add-in system.

Let say I have loaded a nuget package (targeted_package.targeted_version) in a directory.

Along with my requested package, its dependencies are extracted in their own directories.

I now have a file structure which looks like :

```
+--- dependency1_package.dependency1_version
|   +--- lib
|   |   +--- net45
|   |   |   +--- ...
|   |   +--- portable-win8+net45+wp8
|   |   |   +--- ...
|   |   +--- win8
|   |   |   +--- ...
|   |   +--- wp8
|   |   |   +--- ....
|   |   +--- wpa
|   |   |   +--- ....
|   +--- dependency1_package.dependency1_version.nupkg
+--- targeted_package.targeted_version
|   +--- lib
|   |   +--- net40
|   |   |   +--- targeted_assembly.dll
|   +--- targeted_package.targeted_version.nupkg
+--- dependency2_package.dependency2_version
|   +--- lib
|   |   +--- net40
|   |   |   +--- ...
|   |   +--- net45
|   |   |   +--- ...
...
|   +--- dependency2_package.dependency2_version.nupkg
```

I know that targeted_package.targeted_version contains a class with known characteristics. Let's says it implements a known interface and is annotated with a known annotation. But I do not know the name of this class.

From those preconditions, how can I scan the file tree to find this class and proceed to reflection operations on it and/or instantiate it ?

Comment: Why not just use something designed for plug-ins like _MAF_ or _MEF_?  Otherwise how to you differentiate something which is meant to _extend the functionality of an application at runtime_ to something which is essentially a _class library_ to be used at compile-time?

Comment: Actually I don't mind using one of those framework  but did not found any example which works and respect the constraints I listed in my question.  But I will be happy to validate any working answer which use MEF or MAF.